# QTimer: creating objects at timeout

Tags: c++, qt, timer

In my main, I am trying to set a Timer, which creates objects or calls the constructor of an object when the Timer times out. The Object creates a connection to a website that gives back weather data and therefore I want to refresh the weather data when the timer runs out.

My main:

```
QApplication App(argc, argv);

// this is the object that is to be looped
WeatherChecker *wc = new WeatherChecker(&App);
MainWindow w(nullptr, wc);
w.show();
result = App.exec();
```

The WeatherChecker:

```
WeatherChecker::WeatherChecker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    _networkManager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
{
    connect(_networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onResult(QNetworkReply*)));
}
//...some more irrelevant functions
```

I've tried to call the constructor with a timer in my main and I tried to call the connect statement in a separate function with a timer but both ways didn't work out. Any suggestions on how to and where to place the timer?

Comment: What method of `WeatherChecker` should the timer actually invoke?

Comment: Just the constructor of WeatherChecker. The other methods will be executed through the connect statement that is in the constructor.

Comment: But `connect` simply sets up a signal-slot connection. Where do you make the actual HTTP request via `_networkmanager`?

Comment: I did copy my code from [here](https://github.com/kowalskikamil90/weather-checker/blob/master/src/weatherchecker.cpp). But that code doesn't contain a refresh function so that the data is only the most recent when having restarted the program.

Comment: add the code with the timer and the code doing the request. I’d also suggest to use new-style (statically checked) connects.